# Is it possible to redefine the format of wcf messages?

Tags: .net, web-services, web, wcf

I'm working on a server application, which will use web services to communicate with the user clients. I need to make the services accessible on every platform (basically all kinds of mobile phones), so by default using WCF would be painful on the client side, but i was wondering, if there was a not-too-hard way to customize WCF messages, so that i can give an exact, and easy-to-use specification to the client-guys.

Comment: If you using basicHttpBinding - most platforms should cope with that, surely?

Comment: My problem is not that i can't call the service (I'm supposed to be able to), but the format of the messages content is WCF-specific, and not every platform has a library to parse it. Basically i want to tell WCF to serialize classes how I want them, and not how it wants to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick between `DataContractSerializer` (the default) or `XmlSerializer` using an attribute on your service contract. There's also the `NetDataContractSerializer` but you cannot use this with an attribute.

Use `DataContractSerializer`:

```
[DataContractSerializerFormat]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IYourService
{
     ......
}
```

Use `XmlSerializer`:

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IYourService
{
     ......
}
```

If you **really must**, you can define your own serializer to handle serialization totally the way you want (watch out for the amount of work needed for this!).

See [Service Station: Serialization in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) for more info on the serializers